# * quantifier in Perl 6

Tags: regex, match, raku, quantifiers

This seems to be something very basic that I don't understand here.

Why doesn't `"babc"` match `/ a * /` ?

```perl6
> "abc" ~~ / a /
｢a｣
> "abc" ~~ / a * /
｢a｣
> "babc" ~~ / a * /
｢｣                    # WHY?
> "babc" ~~ / a + /
｢a｣
```

Comment: Did you mean `/a*/` and it just came out as `/ a * /` because I'm pretty sure the spaces in a regex matter so the `*` is on the ` ` not the `a`....

Comment: @Artb No they don't matter, and `/a*/` gives just the same result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answers here are correct, I'll just try to present them in a more coherent form:

### Matching always starts from the left

The regex engine always starts at the left of the strings, and prefers left-most matches over longer matches

### `*` matches empty strings

The regex `a*` matches can match the strings `''`, `'a'`, `'aa'` etc.
It will always prefer the longest match it finds, but it can't find a match longer than the empty string, it'll just match the empty string.

### Putting it together

In `'abc' ~~ /a*/`, the regex engine starts at position 0, the `a*` matches as many a's as it can, and thus matches the first character.

In `'babc' ~~ /a*/`, the regex engine starts at position 0, and the `a*` can match only zero characters. It does so successfully. Since the overall match succeeds, there is no reason to try again at position 1.

Comment: Thanks! The only question is why it's made different from standard bash `grep` (where `echo babc | grep 'a*'` will match)?

Comment: The regex does match, it just matches the empty string. If you do a `say so 'babc' ~~ /a*/`, it says True.

Comment: I meant that traditional grep will match a non-empty string (`a` in this case). So what's the idea behind making it different in Perl 6?

Comment: @EugeneBarsky Presumably the regex engine underlying `grep` is matching empty strings too but `grep` chooses not to display them. Additionally, `grep` is presumably defaulting to multiple matching. So `echo babaac | grep 'a*'`, which displays something like "b**a**b**aa**c", corresponds to `say "babaac" ~~ m:g/ a * /`, which displays `(｢｣ ｢a｣ ｢｣ ｢aa｣ ｢｣ ｢｣)`.

Comment: `echo bbbb | grep 'a*'` also matches so grep's behaviour is the same. Grep is showing the lines that match, not the matches themselves.

Comment: @donaldh It normally shows the matches, either with color or using `-o`.

Comment: @EugeneBarsky – hmm. When I try grep with -o it shows the zero length match. Running `echo babc | grep -o 'a*'` prints a blank line, i.e. the line matches and -o provides the matching part of the line which is zero length. If you try it with --color=always it will print `babc` with nothing highlighted. Try it with `ababc` and it prints `ababc` with the first `a` highlighted. There's no difference in behaviour between grep and Perl 6 for `a*`.

Comment: @donaldh What's your system? for `echo babc | grep -o 'a*'` I get `a` in output.

Comment: @EugeneBarsky macOS running grep (BSD grep) 2.5.1-FreeBSD. Interestingly, I have a Linux box with grep (GNU grep) 2.5.1 which exhibits the same behaviour. But a newer Linux box with grep (GNU grep) 2.20 gives the behaviour you describe. The man page on that machine says `Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line`.

Comment: @EugeneBarsky on that machine, `echo bbbb | grep 'a*'` prints `bbbb`. It turns out that since 2005 gnu grep forces non empty matches when using -o or --color so it's behaviour changes if you ask to see the matches – http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/grep.git/commit/?id=268c542052401bc3f3b9d2e006a254da5e3bac28

Comment: @donaldh I've just tested both my Mac (gnu grep 2.21) and Linux (gnu grep 3.1), and they both give `a`. So that seems to be really some ancient behaviour. :)
producing `bbbb` seems logical to me as well.

Comment: GNU grep uses a regex engine called DFA (Deterministic Finite Automaton), which is different from the engine used by Perl (and I guess, Perl6): NFA (Nondeterministic Finite Automaton).
The difference is in how the engine and the text work: the NFA engine is regex-driven, so the regex is matched against the text (and /a*/ matches against the beginning of the string). The DFA engine is test-driven, so the text is examined one character at the time and matched against the regex.

Answer (score 8):

Because `*` quantifier makes the preceding atom match **zero** or more times.

`｢｣` is first match of `/ a * /` in any string. For example:

```perl
say "xabc" ~~ / a * . /; # OUTPUT: ｢x｣
```

it's same:

```perl
say "xabc" ~~ / (a+)? . /;
```

If you set the pattern more precise, you will get another result:

```sh
say "xabc" ~~ / x a * /; # OUTPUT: ｢xa｣
say "xabc" ~~ / a * b /; # OUTPUT: ｢ab｣
```

Comment: That makes sense -- but then why does `"abc" ~~ / a * /` not give the same result?

Comment: @KeithThompson An `a*` pattern (not `a*?`) will match one or more consecutive `a`s -- as many as it can. Give it *zero* `a`s to match and it'll *still* match as many as it can (zero). Either way, it matches and the regex is done unless there's more of the pattern after the `a*`. If there's more pattern then it tries that too. If *that* matches then the regex is done. If not, the regex backtracks and tries again, matching one less `a` to see if that works out. If that fails, it backtracks and matches one less `a`, etc.

Comment: @KeithThompson Similarly, an `a*?` pattern will frugally match one or more consecutive `a`s -- as **few** as it can. It's even happier to match *zero* `a`s than the greedy `a*` without a `?` on the end. But if there's more to the regex pattern, then it continues. If the next bit fails then the engine backtracks and tries matching one **more** `a` rather than one less, and then tries the remainder of the pattern. If it still fails, then it backtracks again etc. (This backtracking behavior only applies if it's a `regex` pattern, not a `token` or `rule`. A `/.../` literal is a `regex`.)

Comment: @raiph Surely you mean zero or more consecutive `a`s when using `a*` – one or more is `a+`. A frugal match such as `a*?` is guaranteed to provide a zero length match regardless of the input. `say "cccc" ~~ /a*?/ # output: ｢｣`

Comment: @donaldh You're right about `a*` and `a+` of course. A silly mistake on my part.

Comment: @donaldh There must be some misunderstanding about about `a*?`. Perhaps I didn't make myself clear about the distinction between a subpattern and an overall regex or that I meant to speak generically about `*` and `*?` without regard for the atom they quantify. Note that your example is the same whether one uses `a*` or `a*?`. Here's a simple counterexample to one literal reading of your comment: `say "1aa2" ~~ /1 a*? 2/ # output: ｢1aa2｣`. But again, that's the same for `a*` and `a*?` Next, consider `say "1aaabab" ~~ /1 [a|b]* <(b.*)>/ # ｢b｣` vs `say "1aaabab" ~~ /1 [a|b]*? <(b.*)>/ # ｢bab｣`.